# Different apostrophes in C

Tags: c

I'm writing a program that reads text files, and reads the characters into an array.

I need it to be done, character by character into the array, and I need to sanitize the characters of whitespace, punctuation, and capitalization.

I already have written the code to do so. However, the assignment that I am following has a specific text document that I am to sanitize.

The problem is that the apostrophes in the document are not being marked by the ispunct function. If I remove the apostrophes in the text document and replace them with normal apostrophes, it works fine. I feel that that is not good enough because I will not be using my own text document for proof of the program's validity.

I have tried including a statement specifically for that apostrophe:

else if(c=='’') [which is pulling from c=fgetc(fp)], I get a multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar].

This small detail is driving me insane, and I can't tell why the apostrophes are different!

***"that’s" Here is a piece of text from the document, when converted to hex equals 74 68 61 74 e2 80 99 73.***

Comment: By the way, the apostrophe that is in the text document is not the usual ', and I am aware the usual apostrophe can be escaped with ispunct as well as \'.

Comment: In order to get the help you want you need to include a [MCVE] in your question.

Comment: I'm wondering if you're getting [Unicode apostrophes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apostrophe#Unicode) in your document.

Comment: Are you sure its an apostrophe ' and not a backtick character `?

Comment: Do you have any assumptions about the encoding type of the input document?

Comment: It would really help if you would construct a very small document, containing a single word and one of the apostrophes that's a problem (perhaps `can't`), and then run that document through a hex dump program and paste the dump into your question.

Comment: N.B. If Fred Larson is right about what's going on (and I think he probably is) then this will be much easier in a recent version of Perl, or Python 3.  Are you _required_ to do this in C?

Comment: You need to construct a small document showing the error and examine the binary. As Fred says, likely you have a unicode apostrophe embedded in there. You can easily enough patch the sanitiser if you know the rogue code.

Comment: The only languages I am allowed to use, are C, C++, and Java. I went with C, because it's the most familiar language for me.

Comment: `74 68 61 74 e2 80 99 73` -- yep, that's a Unicode apostrophe, encoded in UTF-8.  The letters 't' 'h' 'a' 't' and 's' are each encoded as a single byte (74, 68, 61, 74, and 73 respectively) but the apostrophe (U+2019 RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK) is encoded as the three-byte sequence `e2 80 99`.  A C `char` can only hold a single byte, so you can see, I hope, that `c == '’'` is never going to work.

Comment: *The only languages I am allowed to use, are C, C++, and Java* — Of the three, this will be easiest in Java, in which the equivalent of `c == '’'` would actually have worked.  However, if you give us the _complete_ specification of what your program needs to do (we don't know what you mean by "sanitize the characters of whitespace, punctuation, and capitalization"), we can try to explain how to do it in C.

Comment: Well, the entire specifications of the program are to read two text files into arrays. I need to sanitize the text of one the files, to pure plaintext. The other file I read into the program is a cipher-key into a matrix. That function of the program I already have complete. Then, I take the sanitized plaintext array, and break it up into an array of length 2, and use the cipher mechanism to encrypt the plain text to cipher text. For that, I also have the math and methodology down. However, without the pure plaintext input array, the whole program fails its purpose.

Comment: How are punctuation, capital letters, and whitespace not "pure plaintext"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps your input is [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) encoded (which is a good thing, read about [UTF8 everywhere](http://utf8everywhere.org/)). Only you (or your user) can tell that (but read about [byte order marks)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark). On Linux, the [file(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/file.1.html) command can often guess UTF-8 encoded textual files.

But UTF-8 is a variable byte encoding (some [Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) characters are represented by *several* bytes, and in almost all C11 implementations, a byte is a `char`) and is not known by recent [C11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C11_(C_standard_revision)) standard. So you need to *parse* your byte stream as UTF-8. Notice that  [strlen](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strlen) no longer gives the number of (or the length in) UTF-8 *characters* but simply the length in *bytes*. So you should think of `char` as meaning a *byte*, not a Unicode character.

I recommend using some external library for UTF-8 parsing, like [Glib Unicode Manipulation](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Unicode-Manipulation.html) functions or the much simpler [libunistring](https://www.gnu.org/software/libunistring/). If you are not allowed to use such an external library, you could ignore every *multibyte* UTF-8 characters by skipping every `char` whose higher bit is set (but that might be tricky if you want to write portable C code, since some C implementations have `char` the same as `signed char` and other implementations have `char` the same as `unsigned char`). I don't recommend using `wchar_t` which is implementation and operating system specific (and different on Linux and Windows).

> I have tried `else if(c=='’')`

Your C source file containing the above code chunk is (very likely) also UTF-8 encoded, so the character literal `'’'` is a multi-byte character literal (like `'ab'` or `'⬮'` also is), actually it is a *`U+2019 RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK`* and the same as `'\342\200\231'`, and its interpretation is implementation specific. In general you should want to avoid such multi-byte characters in your C source code (outside of literal strings like `"éx⁂"` or comments).

Comment: Yes, as you and several others have brought to my attention it appears that the apostrophes are in fact Unicode. Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with dealing with Unicode in C, and attempting to switch to wchar and wctype, have not brought me much in the way of reigning in these errant apostophes.

Comment: @L.Stein Yeah, wchar and wctype were designed in the days before Unicode took over the world and are basically useless nowadays—they are trying to solve a bunch of problems you don't have, and they don't even try to solve the problem you do have.

Comment: After a lot of review, and research (I'm still pretty much a beginner as far as C goes) I found the limits.h library, and after setting an if statement to ignore characters over* the CHAR_MAX, it eliminated the Unicode characters and has granted me a sanitized plaintext! Thank you so much for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

A better approach might be to think about what characters are left after you've stripped all the illegal ones. If it's just `a-z`, and a few others, that's an easy-to-detect range.