# C++ read file word by word without any symbol

Tags: c++, string, parsing, ifstream, lexical-analysis

I want to read word by word from a text file. Here's my code in C++:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    // insert code here...

    ifstream file("./wordCount.txt");
    string word;
    while(file >> word){
        cout<<word<<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The text file contains the sentence:

```
I don't have power, but he has power.
```

Here's the result I get:

```
I
don\241\257t
have
power,
but
he
has
power.
```

Can you tell me how to get the result like the below format:

```
I
don't
have
power
but
he
has
power
```

Thanks.

Comment: Looks like the file is not quite the expected character encoding. Make sure the `'` isn't a `’`

Comment: @user4581301 Just checked ' , no problem.

Comment: Do you have access to a hex editor or file reader with a hexadecimal view?

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44726106/841108) answer to a similar question

Answer (score 5):

I understand that you're looking for getting rid of the punctuation.

Unfortunately, extracting strings from a stream looks only for spaces as separator.  So "don't" or "Hello,world" would be read as one word, and "don' t" or "Hello, world" as two words.

The alternative, is to read the text line by line, and use [`string::find_first_of()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find_first_of/) to jump from separator to separator:

```
string separator{" \t\r\n,.!?;:"};
string line; 
string word;
while(getline (cin, line)){  // read line by line 
    size_t e,s=0;            // s = offset of next word, e = end of next word 
    do {
        s = line.find_first_not_of(separator,s);  // skip leading separators
        if (s==string::npos)                  // stop if no word left
            break;
        e=line.find_first_of(separator, s);   // find next separator 
        string word(line.substr(s,e-s));      // construct the word
        cout<<word<<endl;
        s=e+1;                                // position after the separator
    } while (e!=string::npos);                // loop if end of line not reached
}
```

[Online demo](http://ideone.com/3Sz7yd)

Answer (score 1):

The code below, gets rid of punctuation, except of the apostrophe:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    ifstream file("wordCount.txt");
    string word;
    while(file >> word) {
        for (auto c : word)
            if (ispunct(c) && c != '`')
                word.erase(word.find_first_of(c));
        cout << word << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

should produce the desired output:

```
Georgioss-MacBook-Pro:~ gsamaras$ g++ -Wall -std=c++0x main.cpp 
Georgioss-MacBook-Pro:~ gsamaras$ ./a.out 
I
don`t
have
power
but
he
has
power
```

For the problem with some characters, I encourage you to check the encoding of the file, so try doing (as explained [here](https://superuser.com/questions/151972/determining-the-encoding-of-a-file-on-mac-os-x)):

```
file -I wordCount.txt 
wordCount.txt: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
```

which is what worked for me. Or simply open a text editor and make sure the characters are valid.

Comment: He doesn't want the punctuation in it. (i.e. the period and comma.)

Comment: @Link I think you have misunderstood the question. I think the easiest universal Windows way to do this is open the file in notepad, File->Save As and check the encoding down at the bottom of the Save As dialogue.

Comment: I have fixed don\241\257t problem by using sublime text editor. But How can I get rid of comma and period, I don't want to count them.

Comment: @Link thank you very much, missed that! Do you like it now?

Comment: @xmz see my updated answer. Isn't that what you want?

Comment: @user4581301 Didn't misunderstand at all. :)

Comment: No you didn't. I apologize. I locked in on only the most obvious issue.

Comment: NIce !  But you only remove punctuation in blocks of chars separated by spaces. So "hello,world"  would be interpreted as on word "helloworld", and "hello, world !" would result in 3 words ("hello", "world", and ""), isn't it ?

Comment: Right @Christophe, however I know see there is a second answer as well! ;) Modify it a bit to read from a file, and I will test it, must be that it does the trick in that case. Mine doesn't, well because I focused on OP's case; he can modify it at will! Thanks for upvoting!

Comment: :) just replace the `cin` with `file` in my snippet to get it work from a file.  I just used cin in order to facilitate online tests on ideone.

Comment: @Christophe ok! Good answer.

Comment: There is a difference between ` and '. With plain English, the apostrophe is the later, therefore, your code will trim "**don't**" but keep "**don`t**". Also, the code doesn't handle this "power,but" where there is no space.

Answer (score 0):

To ease debug, I replace the file with std::istringstream.

- easy to add additional test input
- input is thus documented, and repeatable.

I also added a bool (class data attribute) to simplify enable/disable of additional diagnostic information. (m_dbg)

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <chrono>
// 'compressed' chrono access --------------vvvvvvv
typedef std::chrono::high_resolution_clock  HRClk_t; // std-chrono-hi-res-clk
typedef HRClk_t::time_point                 Time_t;  // std-chrono-hi-res-clk-time-point
typedef std::chrono::microseconds           MS_t;    // std-chrono-milliseconds
typedef std::chrono::microseconds           US_t;    // std-chrono-microseconds
typedef std::chrono::nanoseconds            NS_t;    // std-chrono-nanoseconds
using   namespace std::chrono_literals;          // support suffixes like 100ms, 2s, 30us

#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>


class T496_t
{
   std::array<char, 256>     m_keep;
   std::vector<std::string>  m_wordVec;
   bool                      m_dbg = false;

public:

   T496_t()
      {
         for (uint i=0; i<256; ++i)
            m_keep[i] = static_cast<char>(i);
         m_keep[uint(',')] = 0;
         m_keep[uint('.')] = 0;
      }

   ~T496_t() = default;

   int exec()
      {
         std::istringstream file(
            "Hello\n"
            "I don't have power, but he has power.\n"
            "I don't  have power , but he has power.\n"
            ); //ifstream file("./wordCount.txt");

         uint lineCount = 1;
         while(1)
         {
            std::string line;
            (void)std::getline(file, line);
            if(file.eof())
            {
               ltrim(line);
               if(0 != line.size())
                  if(m_dbg) std::cout << __LINE__ << "  tail: " << line << std::endl;
               break;
            }

            if(m_dbg) std::cout << "\n  line " << lineCount++ << " :  '"
                                << line << "'\n  " << std::setfill('-')
                                << std::setw(static_cast<int>(line.size())+12)
                                << "-" << std::setfill(' ');
            std::cout << '\n';


            size_t sz = line.size();
            if(0 == sz)
               continue;     // ignore empty lines

            extractWordsFrom(line); // extract words

            if(file.eof()) break;
         }
         return(0);
      }

private: // methods

   void extractWordsFrom(std::string& unfiltered)
      {
         std::string line; // filtered
         filter(unfiltered, line);

         if(0 == line.size()) {
            if(m_dbg) std::cout << "  empty line" << std::endl; return;
         }

         size_t indx1 = 0;
         do {
            while(isspace(line[indx1])) { indx1 += 1; } // skip leading spaces

            size_t indx2 = line.find(" ", indx1);
            if(std::string::npos == indx2)
            {
               m_wordVec.push_back(line.substr(indx1));
               if(m_dbg) std::cout << "  word(" << std::setw(3) << indx1 << ", eoln): ";
               std::cout << "  " << m_wordVec.back() << std::endl;
               break;
            }

            m_wordVec.push_back(line.substr(indx1, indx2-indx1));
            if(m_dbg) std::cout << "  word(" << std::setw(3) << indx1 << ","
                                << std::setw(3) << indx2 << "): ";
            std::cout << "  " << m_wordVec.back() << std::endl;
            indx1 = indx2+1;

         }while(1);
      }

   void filter(std::string& unfiltered, std::string& line)
      {
         ltrim(unfiltered); // remove leading blanks

         for(uint i=0; i<unfiltered.size(); ++i) // transfer all chars
            if(m_keep[unfiltered[i]])            // exception check
               line.push_back(unfiltered[i]);
      }


   // trim from start
   void  ltrim(std::string &s) {
      s.erase(s.begin(),
              std::find_if(s.begin(), s.end(),
                           std::not1(std::ptr_fun<int, int>(std::isspace)) ));
   }
   // trim from end
   void rtrim(std::string &s) {
      s.erase(std::find_if(s.rbegin(), s.rend(),
                           std::not1(std::ptr_fun<int, int>(std::isspace))).base(),s.end());
   }
   // trim from both ends
   void  lrtrim(std::string &s) { rtrim(s); ltrim(s); }

}; // class T496_t


int main(int /*argc*/, char** /*argv[]*/)
{
  setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
  std::ios::sync_with_stdio(false);

  Time_t start_us = HRClk_t::now();

  int retVal = -1;
  {
     T496_t   t496;
     retVal = t496.exec();
  }

  auto  duration_us = std::chrono::duration_cast<US_t>(HRClk_t::now() - start_us);
  std::cout << "\n\n  FINI   " << duration_us.count() << " us" << std::endl;
  return(retVal);
```

}

---

```
   // desired output:
   // I
   // don't
   // have
   // power
   // but
   // he
   // has
   // power
```

---

Output from this code:

```
  Hello

  I
  don't
  have
  power
  but
  he
  has
  power

  I
  don't
  have
  power
  but
  he
  has
  power
```

---

Output with m_dbg=true

```
  line 1 :  'Hello'
  -----------------
  word(  0, eoln):   Hello

  line 2 :  'I don't have power, but he has power.'
  -------------------------------------------------
  word(  0,  1):   I
  word(  2,  7):   don't
  word(  8, 12):   have
  word( 13, 18):   power
  word( 19, 22):   but
  word( 23, 25):   he
  word( 26, 29):   has
  word( 30, eoln):   power

  line 3 :  'I don't  have power , but he has power.'
  ---------------------------------------------------
  word(  0,  1):   I
  word(  2,  7):   don't
  word(  9, 13):   have
  word( 14, 19):   power
  word( 21, 24):   but
  word( 25, 27):   he
  word( 28, 31):   has
  word( 32, eoln):   power


  FINI   215 us
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach is first to filter the string. Remove any punctuation except apostrophe (i.e. ' ) and replace them with white-space for further manipulation (i.e. to take advantage of some built-in functions).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <sstream>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

bool isOk(char c)
{
    if ( ispunct(c) )
        if ( c == '\'' )
            return false;

    return ispunct(c);
}

int main()
{
    ifstream file("data.txt");
    string word;

    while(file >> word){
        std::replace_if(word.begin(), word.end(), isOk, ' ');
        istringstream ss(word);
        copy(istream_iterator<string>(ss), istream_iterator<string>(), ostream_iterator<string>(cout, "\n"));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
I
don't
have
power
but
he
has
power
```